# Classical deploy a VM using New-AzResource

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

This is how I deploy a VM using Azure Powershell. I am wondering how to convert it to use the classical deployment model using `New-AzResource`

```
$VirtualMachine = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $VirtualMachine -Windows -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credential -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
$VirtualMachine = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $NIC.Id
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $VirtualMachine -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsServer' -Offer 'WindowsServer' -Skus '2019-Datacenter' -Version latest

New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VirtualMachine -Verbose -edgeZone $edgezoneName
```

My attempt:

```
New-AzResource -Location $location `
               -Properties @{VM=$VirtualMachine} `
               -ResourceName $VMName `
               -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines" `
               -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
               -Force `
               -Verbose
```

Comment: Did you have any existing classic VM in or before the month of February 2020 ? If not, you are considered as a "new user" and not allowed to deploy Classic VMs anymore - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-faq#what-is-the-definition-of-a-new-customer-on-iaas-vms--classic--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing research found that  [**`MICRSOFT DOCUMENTATION`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/classic-vm-deprecation) and also same suggested by @Jul_DW,

> ***As of February 28, 2020, customers who didn't utilize IaaS VMs through***
> ***ASM in the month of February 2020 can no longer create VMs (classic)***.

So that we are no longer able to create classic vms instead of that we can use *Azure Resource Manager*.

For more information to create VM using PowerShell please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION.***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-quick-create-vm-windows-powershell?view=azs-2108&tabs=az1%2Caz2%2Caz3%2Caz4%2Caz5%2Caz6%2Caz7%2Caz8)